# Is it possible to combine Hashmap get and put?

Tags: java, hashmap

```
for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
    InputData data = new InputData(reader.readLine());
    IntWrapper x= map.get(data);
    if (x== null) {
        map.put(data, new IntWrapper());
    } else {
        z+=x.i++;
    }
}
```

As I am trying to get my program to run as fast as possible for a class contest, is there a way to combine the get(data) and put(data) together so that the java Hashmap does not need to compute the hash twice? I need to check if the duplicate exists to decide whether to insert the new data into the map or to just increment the duplicate count.

The full code is below:
The aim is to find the number of pairs of lines with the same combination of characters(can be different permutation)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class SpeedDemon {
    static int[] primes = new int[]{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71,
        73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193,
        197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331,
        337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463,
        467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541, 547, 557, 563, 569, 571, 577, 587, 593, 599, 601, 607, 613, 617,
        619, 631, 641, 643, 647, 653, 659, 661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709, 719};

    class IntWrapper{
        int i = 1;
        public IntWrapper(){}
    }

    class InputData {
        int[] dataValues= new int[128];
        int hashcode;
        public InputData(String data) {
            hashcode = 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                int x = (int) data.charAt(i);
                dataValues[x]++;
                hashcode *= primes[x];
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode(){
            return this.hashcode;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            int[] objValues = ((InputData) o).dataValues;

            for (int i = 127; i > -1; i--) {
                if (objValues[i] != this.dataValues[i]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    public int processData(String filename) {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            int size = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
            HashMap<InputData, IntWrapper> map = new HashMap<>(6*size);
            int z=0;

            for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
                InputData data = new InputData(reader.readLine());
                IntWrapper x= map.get(data);

                if (x== null) {
                    map.put(data, new IntWrapper());
                } else {
                    z+=x.i++;
                }
            }
            return z;
        } catch(Exception ex) {

        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpeedDemon dataProcessor = new SpeedDemon();
        int answer = dataProcessor.processData(args[0]);
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use [`compute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) instead. But honestly, the difference in speed here will be dwarfed by the reading from a file.

Comment: `IntWrapper x = map.computeIfAbsent(data, k -> new IntWrapper())`